# UPGRADE FAILED: another operation (install/upgrade/rollback) is in progress

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

Yesterday, I stopped a Helm upgrade when it was running on a release pipeline in Azure DevOps and the followings deployments failed.

I tried to see the chart that has failed with the aim of delete it but the chart of the microservice ("auth") doesn't appear. I used the command «helm list -n [namespace_of_AKS]» and it doesn't appear.

What can I do to solve this problem?

**Error in Azure Release Pipeline**

```
2022-03-24T08:01:39.2649230Z Error: UPGRADE FAILED: another operation (install/upgrade/rollback) is in progress
2022-03-24T08:01:39.2701686Z ##[error]Error: UPGRADE FAILED: another operation (install/upgrade/rollback) is in progress
```

**Helm List**
[image: Helm List]

Comment: `helm ls -a -n {namespace}` will list all releases within a namespace, regardless of status. You can also use `helm ls -aA` instead to list all releases in all namespaces -- in case you actually deployed the release to a different namespace (I've done that before)

Comment: @BlenderFox thank you, your response solved my problem

Comment: @kavyasaraboju-MT thank you for your response. I didn't prove it because I coul fix with the previous response

Comment: @fjalcaraz no problem. I will add as an answer for others to find

Answer (score 159):

This  error can happen for few reasons, but it most commonly occurs when there is an interruption during the upgrade/install process as you already mentioned.

To fix this one may need to, **first rollback to another version, then reinstall** or helm upgrade again.

*Try below command to list*

```
helm ls --namespace <namespace>
```

but you may note that when running that command ,it may not show any columns with  information

*Try to check the history of the previous deployment*

```
helm history <release> --namespace <namespace>
```

This provides with information mostly like the original installation was never completed successfully and is **pending state** something like STATUS: pending-upgrade state.

*To escape from this state, use the rollback command:*

```
helm rollback <release> <revision> --namespace <namespace>
```

revision is optional, but you should try to provide it.

You may then try to issue your original command again to upgrade or reinstall.

Comment: To rollback to the previous revision and you don't know the number of the revision, you can use
`helm rollback <release> 0` and it will do it automatically.

Comment: Do you know how can I reproduce this behavior, in oder to test a automation?

Comment: I use TrueNAS and rolled back to a prior version. After trying the upgrade again, it worked this time.

Comment: To clarify something that confused me for a second : `<release>` is something from the `NAME` column returned by `helm ls`

Answer (score 46):

`helm ls -a -n {namespace}` will list all releases within a namespace, regardless of status.

You can also use `helm ls -aA` instead to list all releases in all namespaces -- in case you actually deployed the release to a different namespace (I've done that before)

Comment: to delete: `helm uninstall {release} -n {namespace}`

Answer (score 29):

Try deleting the **latest helm secret** for the deployment and re-run your helm apply command.

```
kubectl get secret -A | grep <app-name>
kubectl delete secret <secret> -n <namespace>
```

Comment: I had this problem when a deployment failed due to a repository name clash.

I was not able to use rollback. but deleting the secret did it for me! Thanks!

Comment: you saved me from a lot of headache! deleting the secret worked a charm

Comment: to get only latest you can just add `| tail -n 1` in the end of the first command so you will have: `kubectl get secret -A | grep <app-name> | tail -n 1`

Answer (score 6):

I also got the same issue, I solved it by rolling back the Helm release from the [OpenLens](https://github.com/MuhammedKalkan/OpenLens) tool, It was showing as Pending-Upgrade before.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My exact error was

```
Helm upgrade failed: another operation (install/upgrade/rollback) is in progress" or "##[error]Error: UPGRADE FAILED: release <namespace> failed, and has been rolled back due to atomic being set: timed out waiting for the condition
```

The error has 2 potential solutions: Either delete the stuck deployment, or fix something in deployment pipeline.

### Solution #1: Delete the stuck deployment

If this same pipeline has been working until now, it may just be stuck. Time to delete it in the Azure portal!

1. Go the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/#home) > Azure CLI (aka the icon called "Cloud Shell")

[image: Azure portal address bar and header with Cloud Shell icon circled]

2. **az account show**  // This will give which subscription are you in.
3. **az account set --subscription**
4. **az aks get-credentials --name  --resource-group**
5. **kubectl get secrets -n**
6. In this situation, the latest release has a problem, so delete that release by running the following:
7. **kubectl delete secret -n  sh.helm.release.v1..v88** (or whatever the last release was as shown after last command)
8. Run the pipeline again, it works :-)

### Solution #2: Fix the pipeline

If you've just updated your pipeline, or haven't run it yet, you may have a bug. That was the case for my particular Azure DevOps pipeline.

1. The `azure-pipeline.yml` stage is missing some parameters (or whatever the problem is in your pipeline)
2. Fix it.
3. Deployment succeeds!

[image: Successful deployment via Azure DevOps pipeline]

Answer (score 1):

Delete the helm secret associated with the release and re-run the command

Helm3 makes use of the Kubernetes Secrets object to store any information regarding a release. These secrets are basically used by Helm to store and read it's state every time we run "helm upgrade" or "helm install".

First we get all the secrets for the namespace by running:
"kubectl get secrets -n <<namespace"

[image]

Now delete the helm secret associated with the pending release by running the following command:

[image]

Note: Here "gloo-system" is the namespace.